# Drawing/putting pushpin in QGIS map layer for specific lat/long or NGR?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

How do I draw/put a pushpin in QGIS map layer for a specific lat/long or NGR?

In MapInfo it is quite easy but just wanted to learn how to do the same in QGIS. I have version 3.8.3.

Comment: What’s an “NGR”?

Comment: I'm assuming "NGR" is the "National Grid Reference" but clarification is required.

Comment: What do you want the pushpin to do? You can add a point in a point layer at given lat/long with the vertex editor or the Lat Long Tools plugin.